# Why does this MySQL query slow down when more conditions are added?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

So I have two tables:

## 1

```
CREATE TABLE `adstable` (
 `adid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `adbudget` decimal(14,7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000',
 `targetdesktop` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `adactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `user` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `imp_today` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `targetwindows` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`adid`),
 KEY `user_index` (`user`),
 KEY `budget_index` (`adbudget`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `imp_today_index` (`imp_today`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=719102 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

## 2

```
CREATE TABLE `userstable` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `balance` decimal(14,7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `balance_index` (`balance`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

and I have two MySQL queries:

## 1

```
SELECT adstable.adid FROM adstable INNER JOIN userstable ON (adstable.user = userstable.id  ) 
WHERE  
adstable.adactive=1 AND adstable.approved = 1 AND 
adstable.targetdesktop = 1 AND adstable.targetwindows = 1 and 
adstable.adbudget > 0.02 AND userstable.balance > 0.02
ORDER BY adstable.imp_today ASC limit 1
```

## 2

```
SELECT adstable.adid FROM adstable INNER JOIN userstable ON (adstable.user = userstable.id  ) 
WHERE  
adstable.adactive=1 AND adstable.approved = 1 AND 
adstable.adbudget > 0.02 AND userstable.balance > 0.02
ORDER BY adstable.imp_today ASC limit 1
```

The 1st query has an extra condition in the where clause: *adstable.targetdesktop = 1 AND adstable.targetwindows = 1*

However the thing that I can't understand is why the first query takes 2-3 seconds to run, while the second query takes 2-3 seconds.

Notes:

- adstable has around 700k rows
- the second & first query both return the same 2 rows (but the extra
  condition in the 1st query makes it so much slower)
- I ran query 1 by removing *adstable.adactive=1 AND adstable.approved
  = 1 instead* of *adstable.targetdesktop = 1 AND adstable.targetwindows = 1*, and the query ran in 0.001 seconds.

Does anyone know why the second query is so much faster than the first, even though the second returns the same # and type of rows the 1st does?

Comment: My logic says: the more conditions you use -> the more comparisons the engine need to do -> takes more time. Make sure that the fields' types of the adactive & approved fields are "legit" (from what I understand, they should be boolean - not INT or VARCHAR for instance).

Comment: @OfirBaruch I think tinyint(1) and boolean are equivalent?

Comment: yea. Do you test the queries in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @OfirBaruch 
the first query is the same as the 2nd, but with two extra comparisons. However, without those two comparisons, the first query would still return the same rows... so I don't understand the overhead (difference of 2 secs). yes phpmyadmin

Comment: Even if the same rows are being returned - still the engine need to run **all** the conditions. I have no other answer for this matter unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post output from `EXPLAIN` so this is guesswork.  But it seems possible the conditions of your first query are somehow forcing MySQL's query planner to do a full table scan of your `adstable`. It's not a small table, so the scan will take a while.

Try creating a compound index on `(adactive, approved, adbudget, user)` on that table.  That's a covering index for your query. You should read about covering indexes.

```
 ALTER TABLE adactive 
   ADD INDEX act_appr_bud_user (adactive, approved, adbudget, user);
```

That should allow the query planner to random-access and the partially scan an index to satisfy your query. It will likely speed things up.

Notice (as of early 2017) MySQL's query planner ordinarily can use only one index per table to satisfy a query. So lots of indexes on single columns can't help as much as compound indexes chosen for particular queries.

Answer (score 0):

For large tables and `LIMIT 1`, the trick is to get the entire `WHERE` consumed, plus, the `ORDER BY`.  That is not possible, but the ideas here *may* help.

```
WHERE  
adstable.adactive=1 AND
adstable.approved = 1 AND 
adstable.targetdesktop = 1 AND
adstable.targetwindows = 1 and 
adstable.adbudget > 0.02 AND
userstable.balance > 0.02
ORDER BY adstable.imp_today ASC limit 1
```

`adstable` needs

```
INDEX(adactive, approved, targetdesktop, targetwindows, adbudget),
INDEX(adactive, approved, targetdesktop, targetwindows, imp_today)
```

The first 4 columns can be in any order, but the last needs to be last.

The first index deals completely with the `WHERE` for `adstable` but will need to sort.  The second index will do some of the filtering, but avoid the sort and short-circuit the `LIMIT 1`.  The Optimizer may (or may not) pick the better of the two.

You could extend each of them to be "covering", but only by adding onto the end of the list.

In this

```
WHERE  
adstable.adactive=1 AND
adstable.approved = 1 AND 
adstable.adbudget > 0.02 AND
userstable.balance > 0.02
ORDER BY adstable.imp_today ASC limit 1
```

`adstable` needs

```
INDEX(adactive, approved, adbudget),
INDEX(adactive, approved, imp_today)
```

The first 2 columns can be in any order, but the last needs to be last.  Again, they could be extended, on the end, to make them "covering".

If you need to do both queries, then I recommend having all 4 indexes; no single one is optimal.

In both cases, `userstable` needs `INDEX(id, balance)` *unless* you already have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.

The `JOIN` could be replaced by

```
AND ( EXISTS * FROM userstable
         id = adstable.user AND balance > 0.02 )
```

This may (or may not) affect performance.

More in [*My cookbook on indexing*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .